# Nondeterministic communication complexity of Hamming distance

Tags: lower-bounds, communication-complexity, nondeterminism

It is something that I think should be known:
what is nondeterministic communication complexity of following task:

is $H(x,y) \geq k$?

There is an obvious upper bound $k \log(n)$. I would expect this to be tight up to a $o(\log(n))$ additive term (for small $k$). Is this known?

Comment: A slightly better upper bound is $\log \binom{n}{k}$.